# Короткое или длинное тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

В указанных случаях, когда тире надо поставить (1) **между словами**, (2) **между словом и числом** и (3) **между числом и словом**, обычно используют:

- короткое тире без пробелов: суббота–воскресенье, 1 марта–5 апреля, в VI–начале VII века?
- короткое тире с отбивками или пробелами: суббота – воскресенье, 1 марта – 5 апреля, в VI – начале VII века? Как эти отбивки делаются?
- длинное тире: суббота — воскресенье, 1 марта — 5 апреля, в VI — начале VII века?

---

**Между числами** (1916–1918) используются короткие тире без отбивки или с отбивкой?

Answer (score 1):

В таких конструкциях дефис используется только при обозначении приблизительного количества или времени.

> Напр.: день-другой, неделя-другая, напишет письмо-другое, год-два, два-три часа, раза три-четыре, человек двенадцать-пятнадцать, двое-трое мальчиков, вдвоём-втроём; Он вернется в марте-апреле.

Примечание. Если в таких конструкциях количество обозначается цифрами, между ними ставится не дефис, а тире, напр.: человек 12 — 15; ей лет 30 — 35; рублей 200 — 300; это было году в 1950 — 1951-м.

Тире ставится между двумя (и более) словами, которые, сочетаясь друг с другом, означают пределы (значение «от... до») — пространственные, временны́е, количественные: **С Казанского вокзала начнут отходить поезда с табличками «Москва — Кара-Бугаз, через Ташкент — Красноводск» (Пауст.); Ошибочно полагая, что культура конского каштана в северо-западных парках явление не XVIII — XIX веков, а более позднее, удалили все каштаны из Тригорского и с могильного холма Святогорского монастыря (Гейч.); Запасы нефти на Челекене очень невелики и должны быть исчерпаны за первые десять — пятнадцать лет добычи (Пауст.).**

Таким образом правильно:

суббота-воскресенье, 1 марта — 5 апреля, в VI — начале VII века.

[См.: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина. М., 2006 (и более поздние издания).](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=63#pp63)

[Розенталь Д. Э. Справочник по русскому языку. Орфография и пунктуация.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=95#pp95)